# value |@| is not a member of cats.data.Validated

Tags: scala, scala-cats

When I use cats 0.9.0 I can easily do

```
import cats.data.Validated
import cats.data.Validated._
import cats.syntax.all._
import cats.implicits._
val x = Validated.valid[List[String], Int](10)
val y = Validated.valid[List[String], Int](20)
x |@| y
```

This works fine. But for my project i must use Cats 0.7.2.

when I try the same code with cats 0.7.2 then this same code does not work and I get error message `value |@| is not a member of cats.data.Validated`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to compile:

```
import cats.data.Validated
import cats.data.Validated._
import cats.syntax.cartesian._
import cats.instances.list._ // <- this was the missing bit

val x  = Validated.valid[List[String], Int](5)
val y  = Validated.valid[List[String], Int](6)
x |@| y
```

I am not sure how the `cats.implicits._` actually works, but it seems that `import cats.instances.list._` was not being imported.

Comment: I used Cats 0.7.2 and Scala 2.11.8